# What is the probability that a random function $\kappa\times\lambda\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ is constant in $y$ for some $x$?

Tags: probability-theory, set-theory, cardinals

Let $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ be infinite cardinals.  Construct a random function $\phi:\kappa\times\lambda\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ by flipping a fair coin for each element of the domain. What is the probability, $P(\kappa,\lambda)$, that there exists $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\forall x \, \phi(\alpha,x)=0$.  Intuitively, it seems like there should be a cardinal $\eta_\lambda$ (for each $\lambda$) such that:
$P(\kappa,\lambda)=0$ if $\kappa<\eta_\lambda$ and 
$P(\kappa,\lambda)=1$ if $\kappa\geq\eta_\lambda$.
(**EDIT 2**:) However, based on the comments, it sounds like this intuitive question cannot be formalized in a reasonable way. Where should I look to get a better understanding of why this is the case? Are there specific theorems that would be useful for understanding this?

**EDIT 1**: There has been debate in the comments about whether this question is meaningful without specifying a measure on $^{\kappa\times\lambda}2$.  If $X=[0,\frac{1}{2})$, then $[0,1]$ is a disjoint union of $X$ and a translate of $X$. Therefore, $\mu(X)=\frac{1}{2}$ for *any* translation invariant probability measure, $\mu$, on $[0,1]$ (for which $X$ is measurable). So, we can argue that $X$ has measure $\frac{1}{2}$ for *any* probability measure on $[0,1]$ having certain natural properties. In the setting of binary functions on $\kappa\times\lambda$, there are similar "symmetries" akin to translation invariance.  For example, one would expect $\mu(X)=\mu(\{1-\phi:\phi\in X\}$.  So, what I'm interested in is whether one can make an argument about the measure of $Y=\{\phi\in^{\kappa\times\lambda}2:\exists\alpha<\kappa\forall \beta<\lambda(\phi(\alpha,\beta)=0)\}$ that is based on conditions we would want any "uniform" probability measure to satisfy.

Comment: "What is the probability..."  Isn't that a non-measurable event (unless the cardinals are countable)?

Comment: Maybe that's true. Can you say a little more about why it is non-measurable?

Comment: What is the probability distribution? You want to say uniform, yes, but what does it mean here? Over $[0,1]$ we have a notion of length which we can use to bootstrap the idea of uniform distribution. But what is the same notion here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets (i.e. all functions that restrict to a given function on a finite subset of the domain) could correspond to the Borel sets on $[0,1]$. We can measure these sets with Caratheodory's theorem, but I don't think that helps. Why is it necessary to specify a probability distribution in order for the question to be meaningful? Can't we make arguments about probability that only rely on knowing some properties of the distribution and not the entire distribution?

Comment: You are asking "what is the probability". That *literally* requires a distribution in the very question.

Comment: Given any continuous probability density function on $[0,1]$ the probability of the set $\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ (or any countable subset) is $0$. I don't need to know the specific distribution in order to make that argument.  To put it another way, I am asking for a natural way to measure a specific set of functions...not some general way to measure all sets of functions.

Comment: How does wanting a measure for only a special class of functions save you from needing to know about the distribution in that special case?

Comment: @Ari: Well, then, what is the probability of $x\in [0,1]$ to be at most $1/2$? You want to say $1/2$, but your mileage may vary if you very the distribution.

Comment: I think that the spirit of my question was not well communicated (by me).  I've made an edit to the post which hopefully clarifies what sort of an answer I am looking for.  To respond briefly to the previous two comments, I think that it is reasonable to want to prove statements like "given any measure satisfying the natural conditions A, B and C, the measure of X must be $0$".  There may be infinitely many different measures that satisfy A, B and C, but since they all assign the same measure to X, we can argue that X has measure $0$ without specifying which particular measure we are using.

Comment: Ari, there is not unclear communication. We are simply trying to walk you to the epiphany, that there are some incredible difficulties hidden under the surface there. I think that everyone involved in the comments know that, and we all try to make you understand that as well. Not everything can be generalised this easily from the natural and real numbers to arbitrary cardinals.

Comment: That is not at all hard to believe, but I don't actually know what those difficulties are concretely.  So, I think I should change my question to "why can't this intuition be formalized" (I'll make another edit to the post).  I would really appreciate it if you could respond with some specific theorems that indicate some of the difficulties. Thank you for your helpful comments so far!

Comment: For starter, cylindrical sets are not going to generate even remotely "most" of the subsets. So you could argue that in a sense, yes, that's a way to measure probability, but if your $\sigma$-algebra ends up entirely of sets which are eventually $0$ on all fibers on a tail below $\kappa$ (i.e., satisfy the property you're interested), then the answer is $1$. If your $\sigma$-algebra is much larger, perhaps the answer is different.

Comment: I did not understand the first part of your comment.  Can you clarify what you mean by "sets which are eventually $0$ on all fibers on a tail below $\kappa$?

Comment: I literally clarified that in the parenthetical remark in the same sentence. I'm not sure what more I can add to that.

Comment: I think I am just confused about the sentence construction.  It sounds like you are saying "if all of the sets in your $\sigma$-algebra have the property you are interested in...".  But that doesn't make sense, since the property I am interested in is a property of functions, not of sets of functions.  Do you understand my confusion?

Answer (score 1):

**Special case**  $P(\aleph_0,\aleph_0) = 0$.
Let $\kappa = \lambda = \aleph_0$.  All subsets of $\kappa \times \lambda$ are Borel sets.  For each $\alpha \in \kappa$, [assuming indpendence, which is not stated]
$$
\mathbb P \big(\{\forall x \in \lambda, \phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\big) =
\mathbb P \left(\bigcap_{x \in \lambda} \{\phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\right) =
\prod_{x\in\lambda} \mathbb P\big(\{\phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\big) = \prod_{x \in \lambda}\frac{1}{2} = 0.
$$
so that
$$
P(\kappa,\lambda) = \mathbb P\big(\{\exists \alpha \in \kappa,
\forall x \in \lambda, \phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\big)
=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa}
\{\forall x \in \lambda, \phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\right) = 0
$$
a countable union of sets of measure zero.

**What if $\lambda$ is uncountable?**
Then for each $\alpha\in \kappa$, the event
$$
\bigcap_{x \in \lambda} \{\phi(\alpha,x)=0\} \subseteq
\bigcap_{x \in \lambda_0} \{\phi(\alpha,x)=0\}
$$
for some countably infinite subset $\lambda_0 \subseteq \lambda$, so it is a subsetof a Borel set of measure zero.  Let's assume our probability measure is complete.  Then we conclude
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{x \in \lambda} \{\phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\right) = 0
$$
anyway.

**what if $\kappa$ is uncountable?**
Then we get
$$
P(\kappa,\lambda) = \mathbb P\big(\{\exists \alpha \in \kappa,
\forall x \in \lambda, \phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\big)
=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa}
\{\forall x \in \lambda, \phi(\alpha,x)=0\}\right)
$$
an uncountable union of (possibly non-Borel) sets of measure zero.  Even if it is measurable (which we do not know), we do not know that it still has measure zero.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up!  I came to the same conclusions you did, and I am mainly interested in where to go from your statement: "Even if it is measurable, we don't know if it has measure 0".  By "measurable", do you mean Borel?  Or something analogous to Lebesgue measurable?  Since there are many possible measures, my question is: can we find a natural measure for which the given set is measurable.  By "natural", I mean a measure that satisfies various properties we would expect (e.g. Replacing $\phi$ with $1-\phi$ for all $\phi$ in a set should not change the measure of the set).